IntellJ not letting select main class of my spring boot application
Screenshot of the problem
Im trying to add the main class to my spring boot application so I can run it. I dont know why it isnt letting me select it.I am using intellJ.

Similar with this thread, try the accepted answers in order please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795758/intellij-run-configuration-cant-find-spring-boot-class

Try these in order:
Check Classpath: Make sure that your project's classpath is set up correctly. IntelliJ IDEA should automatically detect main classes annotated with @SpringBootApplication or public static void main(String[] args) methods in your project. If it's not detecting the main class, there might be an issue with your project configuration.
Reimport Maven/Gradle Project: If you're using Maven or Gradle for your project, try reimporting the project to ensure that IntelliJ IDEA has all the necessary dependencies and configurations. You can do this by clicking on the "Reimport All Maven Projects" or "Refresh Gradle Project" button in the Maven or Gradle tool window, respectively.
Check Project Structure: Verify that the project structure is set up correctly in IntelliJ IDEA. Make sure that your main class is located in the correct source directory (usually src/main/java) and that the package structure matches the package declaration in the main class.
Enable Auto-detection: In IntelliJ IDEA, auto-detection of main classes is usually enabled by default. However, you can check if it's enabled in the project settings. Go to "File" > "Project Structure" > "Modules", select your module, and make sure that the "Sources" tab includes the correct source directories.
Clean and Rebuild: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project to see if that resolves the issue. You can do this by selecting "Build" > "Build Project" from the IntelliJ IDEA menu.
Check for Errors: Look for any error messages or warnings in the IntelliJ IDEA console, Event Log, or Problems tool window. Addressing any errors or warnings may help resolve the issue.
